# Build error when adding firestore plugin to my flutter application

Tags: android, database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter application in Android Studio. I am working with Google Firebase Authentication, Cloud Firestore and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) libraries. As you can see  I have following dependencies in my flutter pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1
  flutter_blue: ^0.6.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1
```

but when I try to add  `cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1` then it gives me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar 
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$3 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$4 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$JavaType found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$3 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I think its a compatibility issue with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) library?

Comment: same issue. any update ?

Comment: looks like there's an answer now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error, I fixed it by using the newer or newest version of **flutter blue** from `flutter_blue: ^0.6.2` to `flutter_blue: ^0.7.0` or up to the latest version:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1
  flutter_blue: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1
```

It seems the lower version of **flutter blue** was deprecated and not recommended. To see the changes of newer version of **flutter blue**, visit this [flutter blue changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/changelog).